# Finding the billionth number in the series: $2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19, 28, 42, \ldots $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Series is defined as
$$a_{n+1} = \lfloor\frac{3\cdot a_n}{2}\rfloor,\qquad  a_0 = 2$$
It can be viewed as the number of animals starting from a single pair if any pair of animals can produce a single offspring.

The problem is if the most straightforward computer program was implemented (recurrence relation in a loop), it seems it would not finish for the lifetime of its creator...
**How to approach this differently?**

EDIT: This number is very large. Its approximation in scientific notation (let's say first 10 decimal digits, and decimal exponent) would be sufficient.

Comment: You might be able to find something useful on the page for this sequence at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A061418).

Comment: This number is absurdly large, with around $176$ million digits. Did you want an approximation to the number in scientific notation? The last $n$ digits? This question can not be reasonably answered as given, without busting MSE answer length constraints.

Comment: Approximation in scientific notation would be sufficient. @Mario Carneiro

Comment: Might be worth adding that $[ \cdot ]$ denotes a Gauss bracket!

Comment: Incidentally, I believe you're wrong that a straightforward program 'would not finish for the lifetime of its creator' - multiplying a number by three is an easy operation, as is the floored divide by two, and with proper care you can work with numbers of the size of each step; it's true that you would probably have to do on the order of $10^{16}-10^{17}$ 32-bit integer operations, but that's no longer nearly the implausibility that it once was.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki, you are right - but my expression "for the lifetime of the creator" was meant mopre to be "artistic description" than exact statement :). Anyway, thanks for comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The related series $$x_n=\lceil\frac32x_{n-1}\rceil,\ x_0=1$$ is studied at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerCeilings.html). Since for all integers $n$, $\lceil\frac32n\rceil=\lfloor\frac32(n+1)\rfloor-1$, we can rewrite this as $x_n+1=\lfloor\frac32(x_{n-1}+1)\rfloor$, and $x_0+1=2$; thus we have $a_n=x_n+1$ for all $n$. That page (links to a paper that) derives that there exists a real number $K$ such that for all $n$, $$x_n=\lceil K(3/2)^n\rceil,$$ which tells us that the sequence very nearly follows the expected power law, although the accumulated roundoff error $K$ is hard to calculate in advance.

So let's take the direct route. Define the sequences $a_{k+1}^+=\frac32a_k^+$,  $a_{k+1}^-=\frac32a_k^--1$, where the initial values set $a_m^+=a_m^-=a_m$ for some fixed basepoint $m$. Then it is easy to show that

$$a_n^+=\Big(\!\frac32\!\Big)^{n-m}a_m;\qquad a_n^-=\Big(\!\frac32\!\Big)^{n-m}(a_m-2)+2.$$

Now we have the inequality $a_n^-\le a_n\le a_n^+$ because $x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, so this directly gives bounds on $a_n$ for $n=10^9$. Since you want around 10 digits of accuracy, we need to pick an $a_m\ge 2\cdot 10^{10}$: for example, $a_{58}=26510400994$. Then we have:

$$\log_{10}(a_m-2)\le\log_{10}a_n-(n-m)\log_{10}(3/2)\le\log_{10}a_m$$
$$\log_{10}26510400992\le\log_{10}a_{10^9}-(10^9-58)\log_{10}(3/2)\le\log_{10}26510400994$$
$$176091259.2658045137\underline{02}\le\log_{10}a_{10^9}\le176091259.2658045137\underline{34}$$

Thus the exponent of $a_{10^9}$ is $176091259$, and the fractional part is $10^{0.2658045137}\approx1.844185120$ (where only the digits that agree for both bounds are shown). Putting it all together, we have

$$a_{10^9}=1.844185120\dots\times10^{176091259}.$$

By repeating this process with bigger basepoints, you can confirm as many digits as you want. Here's a few more correct digits:

$$a_{10^9}=1.844185120759922192245258053300812265366889206992486395592885\times10^{176091259}.$$

Comment: Excellent approach!!

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't give 10 decimal digits, it is the most complete, so I marker it as the ANSWER! Computing 10 digits is trivial once the answer is understood.

Comment: @VividD Ah, I didn't see that you had requested a specific number of digits. I updated the answer to use 10 digits instead of 6, and also threw in as many digits as I could fit without looking stupid at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I think some graphs like these ones can be very helpful...where $$A061418(n) = a_{n+1} = \Big\lfloor\frac{3\cdot a_n}{2}\Big\rfloor,\qquad  a_0 = 2$$
[image]

You can easily see that the *Logarithimc scatterplot* seems to grow linearly, so if you're alloking for an approximation of the billionth number of the sequence you can start from the second graph. With a bit of homemade linear interpolation you get that $$\log(a_n) \approx n\cdot 0,6\overline{1} = n \frac{11}{18} \Rightarrow \\ a_n\approx e^{n \frac{11}{18}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Computing by brute force, we get that $a_{62}=134208905031$. That has $11$ significant figures. Since the error is multiplied by the same factor as the significant part, if we use this number and multiply by $\left(\frac32\right)^{999999937}$ and $\left(\frac32\right)^{999999938}$, we get
$$
a_{999999999}\doteq1.2294567472\times10^{176091259}
$$
and
$$
a_{1000000000}\doteq1.8441851208\times10^{176091259}
$$
to $10$ places, depending on which you mean by "billionth".

Comment: Great, +1 for first answer with exact value as stated in the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A061418) for $2,3,4,6,9,13,19,28,42,\ldots$, adjusted to agree with the OP's starting index, says that

$$a_n=\lceil K(3/2)^{n+1}\rceil$$

where $K\approx1.0815136685898448773046339885995$, with more digits available at a linked-to reference.  If all you want is an approximation in scientific notation, then the ceiling function round-up can be ignored.

Let's let $n=10^9$.  Then Wolfram Alpha gives us

$$\left({3\over2}\right)^{n+1}\approx 1.70518891653445589648412113069806868 × 10^{176091259}$$

and thus

$$a_n\approx1.8441851207599221922452580533 × 10^{176091259}$$

with agrees with what robjohn and others found, with a few more digits.  (I truncated a few digits from the WA output, to stay on the safe side.)